# tblr Caption not working with Springer Nature

Tags: tables, tblr

I'm using `tblr` since it is easier to create good looking tables using these package, but they are not working with Springer Nature.

The code is attached and the problem is shown in the figure.

```
    \documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{xcolor}%
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, varwidth}
    
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{cleveref}
    %\usepackage{float}     % not recommended 
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
    \begin{tblr}
    {
      colspec = {|m{0.03\textwidth}|  % <-- use 'm', not 'p', 
                  m{0.03\textwidth}| 
                  Q[c,{0.03\textwidth}]|
                  Q[c,{0.03\textwidth}]|
                  Q[c,{0.03\textwidth}]|
                    },
    hline{1,2} = {1pt,solid},
    hline{3-5,7-9,11-13,15-17} = {dashed},
    hline{6,10,14,18} = {solid},
    row{1} = {gray!30},
     %  cell{4-8,10-16,20-24,28-32,36-40}{2}={c=2}{h,0.6\paperwidth},
      measure=vbox,
      row{1-Z} = {font=\small},
    cell{1}{1-Z} = {font=\small\bfseries},
    cell{1-Z}{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
    %   cell{1,9,17,25,33}{1-2} = {font=\small\bfseries},
    } 
    x & y & c & d & l \\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{YYYYYYYYY.}
    \label{tabVII}
    \end{table}

\Cref{tabVIII} outlines \dots

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you shouldn't ignore error messages.

Comment: Don't load `caption` with Springer classes: it's incompatible.

Answer (score 5):

The class is faulty. It uses commands from packages that it doesn't load.

```
\documentclass{sn-jnl}

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

errors with

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\__hook begindocument ->\SetFootnoteHook 
                                         {\hspace *{-8pt}}\DeclareNewFootnot...
l.214 \begin{document}
                      
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\__hook begindocument ...8pt}}\DeclareNewFootnote 
                                                  {A}[gobble]\setlength {\sk...
l.214 \begin{document}
                      
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \skip \footinsA 
                           
l.214 \begin{document}
                      
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.214 \begin{document}
                      
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\__hook begindocument ...tinsA }{0pt}\definecolor 
                                                  {artcatboxgray}{cmyk}{0.0,...
l.214 \begin{document}
                      
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\__hook begindocument ...}}}{}\allowdisplaybreaks 
                                                  \Gm@savelength {paperwidth...
```

You can repair that by loading the missing packages:

```
\documentclass{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no such error with `sn-jnl` 2019/11/18 v0.1

Comment: @egreg I just downloaded from here https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support#c18782880 and it failed. And the screenshot above with the A[gobble] is clearly from the missing manyfoot. (The version is the same: 2019/11/18 v0.1)

Comment: Yes, apparently they “fixed” the class, but forgot to 1. test it; 2. change the version number.

Comment: How can I get to the version that doesn't show the error

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved by switching to `longtblr` and removing the `\begin{table}\end{table}`as in

```
\begin{longtblr}[caption={},label={}]
\end{longtblr}
```

there was no solution found for `tblr`

Answer (score 0):

I followed a similar approach as [@Diana](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/98778/diana) using `talltblr` instead of `longtblr`  and some additional formatting customisation:

```tex
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}{\textbf{Table\hspace{0.25em}\thetable}}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}{\enskip}


\begin{talltblr}[caption={},label={}]
\end{talltblr}
```