# using caption in table environment with the sn-mathphys-ay class gives duplicate same identifer warning (ext4): (name{table.1})

Tags: tables

I am using the sn-mathphys-ay class of Springer. When using the table without the caption it compiles with no warning but when a caption is used it give the error

*warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{**table.1**}) has been already used, duplicate ignored*

I have tried all solutions proposed for the same problem where it is either name{page.1} or name{figure.1} or other and not name{**table**.1} that is reported and nothing worked. I looked at one post that seem to say there was a bug in the class file and the package tabularray should be used with some redefinition of the table environment
Here: [tblr Caption not working with Springer Nature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692156/tblr-caption-not-working-with-springer-nature).
I am looking for a simpler solution without the tabularray package and all the necesary other commands as per post above.
I have removed all other code lines that are not relevant in my MWE below. Compiling this gives the above duplicate error but here for the **table.1** name. Removing the **`\caption{Some functions}`** but keeping the `\label{TableEB}` and `\ref{TableEB}` commands, removes the caption and sets the table counter to 1 and shows the correct reference to Table 1 but with **no heading** to show this is Table 1 and it compiles **without** the above warning on the duplicate name for the table. It is the caption that is causing the problem here or at least I believe as I have pined it down to this problem.

Any help would be appreciated how to resolve using `\caption` without the duplicate name for   **table**.1.

Here is my MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{amsthm} %% Put the amsthm package before fixes a bug also here
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys-ay]{sn-jnl}% Math and Phys author-year class
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{anyfontsize}% Fixes a bug with font size
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

This is table \ref{TableEB}:

\begin{table}[tbp]\caption{Some functions}\label{TableEB}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule $x$ & $y$ & $z$ \\
\midrule $x^2$ & $y^3$ & $z-\sqrt{z}+e^z$ \\
\botrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is the outputs with (with compiling error) and without (without compiling error) the `\caption{Some functions}` command leaving the rest intact:

[image: With \caption]

[image: Without \caption]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class has many issues, e.g. relying on macros defined by packages which itself does *not* load.

The problem here is that the class loads `hyperref`, and in your preamble `algorithm` loads the `float` package which, however, should be loaded *before* `hyperref`.

Quick fix: load `float` before `\documentclass`.

```
\RequirePackage{float}
\documentclass[pdflatex]{sn-jnl}% Math and Phys author-year class
\usepackage{amsmath}%  necessary for the class to work
\usepackage{xcolor}%   necessary for the class to work
\usepackage{manyfoot}% necessary for the class to work
\usepackage{algorithm}%
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}% 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% loads algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

This is table \ref{TableEB}:

\begin{table}[tbp]\caption{Some functions}\label{TableEB}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule $x$ & $y$ & $z$ \\
\midrule $x^2$ & $y^3$ & $z-\sqrt{z}+e^z$ \\
\botrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```